# Scipy: Partition array into 3 subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am trying to figure out whether there's a numpy/scipy function to efficiently partition an array into subarrays using a certain rule.

My problem is the following:
I have a nxn matrix, lets call it W. And I have a vector h.
I now want to partition the column vectors of W into 3 arrays:

- W_pos, where  > 0 for all vectors w from W_pos
- W_null, where  = 0 for all vectors w from W_null
- W_neg, where  < 0 for all vectors w from W_neg

Right now I am doing it like this, which is working but I think it is not very efficient:

```
    nonzero_indices = (sp.isclose(sp.dot(h_k.T, W),0, 10e-12) == False)
    self.W_null = W[:,~nonzero_indices]

    W_nonzero = W[:,nonzero_indices]
    pos_indices = (sp.dot(h_k.T, W_nonzero) > 0)
    W_pos = W_nonzero[:,pos_indices]
    W_neg = W_nonzero[:,~pos_indices]
```

Is there a better way? Thanks for your help and if there something not clear please let me know.
Cheers

Comment: Where's the inefficiency?  Generating the masks, or in indexing?

Answer (score 2):

```
w=np.random.random((10,10))-0.5 # example array
```

.

```
wneg = w[w<0]

wzero = w[w==0]

wpos = w[w>0]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How is this faster than my version? In this case I would have to go through the entire array 3 times, once for each partition(pos/neg/zero).

Comment: You have to do timings.  At this level of coding, reasoning only gets you so far.  I suspect indexing takes longer than generating the masks.